# Python is not checking if the systematically randomized generated password is equal to the given password

Tags: python, for-loop, passwords

Essentially I am trying to create a program that can go through all possible passwords one can create with aaaa-zzzz. I have the code down where it can count the number of passcodes and what they are such as 'abcd' or 'xkyz'. However when I try to implement the checking part of the code to pretty much tell it to stop and that the answer has been found, the program negates it and will go all the way down to 'zzzz' even if the given password is 'aaaa'.

```
import random
import sys
my_password = "aaaa"
guess_num = 0
done = False
while not done:  #setup for the loop

my_password = "aaaa"
prime = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',]
prime2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',]
prime3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',]
prime4 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',]
for a in prime:
    for b in prime2:
        for c in prime3:
            for d in prime4:
                first = (a + b + c + d) #loop that goes through  all aaaa-zzzz
                guess = str(first)
                if guess == my_password:
                    print("found it after ", str(guess_num), " tries")
                    done = True
                elif guess != my_password:
                    guess_num = guess_num + 1
                    print(guess, guess_num)
```

print(guess)

Comment: What kind of code is it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean but its python if that is what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) to generate your password guesses. Then you can simplify your code to a simple loop:

```
import itertools
import string

guess_num = 1
my_password ='abcd'
prime = string.ascii_lowercase     # abc...xyz
for guess in itertools.product(prime, repeat=4):
    if ''.join(guess) == my_password:
        print(f"found it after {guess_num} tries")
        break
    guess_num += 1
```